# Match sizes of subplots with gridspec

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, subplot

I'm plotting the output of a Gaussian fitting script I've written in python and am looking to plot the output in a single figure showing the original data and lineout plots of the major and minor axes.

To do this I've used `matplotlib.gridspec` to define a grid then add plots of top of it. However, the lineout plot above the image is much wider than the image itself and I would like them to be the same size, preferably by shrinking slightly the plot.

```py
fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)
gs = GridSpec(4, 4, figure=fig)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1:4,0:3])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0,0:3])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1:4,3])

ax1.imshow(Z, cmap=cm.jet, origin='lower', extent=(x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()))
ax1.plot(Ly,y[:,0],color=[0.8, 0, 0],linewidth=2)
ax1.plot(x[0,:],Lx,color=[0, 0.8, 0],linewidth=2)
ax1.axis([x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()])

ax2.plot(x[0,:],xFit,color=[0, 0.8, 0],linewidth=2)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 1, step=0.5))
ax2.axis([x.min(), x.max(), 0, 1])
ax2.grid()

ax3.plot(yFit,y[:,0],color=[0.8, 0, 0],linewidth=2)
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 1, step=0.5))
ax3.xaxis.tick_top()
ax3.axis([0, 1, y.min(), y.max()])
ax3.grid()

plt.show()
```

Currently, this is the output that I am getting:

[image]

Any help or suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: I fear it's not possible if using `constrained_layout`. Is that a requirement? Else, there are two main options: (a) define the gridspec with square dimensions (that will require to set the left,right,top,bottom parameters depending on the figure size), (b) Not use gridspec, but the `axis_grid1` submodule, as shown e.g. [jhere](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axes_grid1/scatter_hist_locatable_axes.html).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks, Using gridspec or the `constrained_layout` was never a requirement for me. I've re-written the whole plot in terms of the `axis_grid1` submodule and I'm now getting exactly the plot I was after.

https://imgur.com/a/f21VgS6